# Shelveset for webstorm with TFS plugin

Tags: tfs, webstorm, shelveset

TFS plugin for webstorm doesn't support creating Shelveset on server. Is there any other plugin available to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the Team Explorer Everywhere support creating command-line shelve sets?

Comment: @DaveShaw Indeed it does.

Comment: 4.5 years later creating a shelveset on the server via webstorm is still not possible.  My alternative has been to create a new branch, create a patch from the current branch, apply the patch to that new branch, then push the new branch to the server. It's not the most ideal because of the number of steps, but it has worked out as a decent alternative.